# MpMovieplayer crash during reminder alert popup

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am having this strange issue. When I am playing any video using `MpMoviePlayerController`, if I get any **reminder alert** and I choose **Close**, then my application is crashing with Log :

> "An AVPlayerItem cannot be associated with more than one instance of
>   AVPlayer".

I am using only one instance of `MpPlayerController`.

I googled on this issue and found that this can be avoided if I set the property `useApplicationAudioSession = NO`  of `MpMoviePlayerController`, then I am not having any crashes. 
But the thing is this property is **deprecated** after IOS6 and apple doesn't recommend to use this property.

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that the issue is that your audio session is being interrupted by the audio ping of the alert message. Try using the shared instance to get your audio session. Then set a notification listener to handle the interruption properly. See apples guidelines here [Handle Audio Interruptions](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/HandlingAudioInterruptions/HandlingAudioInterruptions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007875-CH11-SW9%20%22Apple%20Guide%20For%20Audio%20Interuptions)

```
NSError *setCategoryError = nil;
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:      &setCategoryError];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(interruptionHandler:) name:AVAudioSessionInterruptionNotification object:nil];
```

Comment: zimmryan, I had checked that. beginInterruption: and  endInterruption: method of AVAudioSessionDelegate is getting triggered only for Alarm clock interrupt and not for calendar reminder alert.  Its strange that these delegate methods are not triggered for Reminder :( :( :(

Comment: It seems that the delegate and interruption callbacks are also deprecated and that you should listen for the notifications AVAudioSessionInterruptionOption and AVAudioSessionInterruptionOptionShouldResume

Comment: I have managed to put a workaround by pausing the player programatically when ... application is about to resign active state and playing the video when the application comes to foreground. Kind of working. 
Im still wondering why the interrupt method is not triggering for Calender/Reminder alert , where as it is triggered for Alarm clock

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is : `AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient`

See descriptions of all the [“Audio Session Categories”](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/AudioSessionBasics/AudioSessionBasics.html).

This should Work for you :

```
NSError *setCategoryError = nil;
BOOL success = [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance]
                 setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient
                 error: &setCategoryError];
```

as Described In : [Setting the Category](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/AudioSessionBasics/AudioSessionBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007875-CH3-SW7).

Comment: Vin, I tried all these three  properties declared in AVAudioSession.h (Still no luck):



  AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient;
, AVAudioSessionCategorySoloAmbient;

,AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback;